# what is the Default user-Agent of PyQt Web kit Qwebview and how to get it

Tags: python, pyqt, qwebview

i am new to python and developing a GUI in PyQt which has a Web Browser. I want to show the User-Agent going with the Url but not founding a way.my code is -

```
class Manager(QNetworkAccessManager):
def __init__(self, table):
    QNetworkAccessManager.__init__(self)
    self.finished.connect(self._finished)
    self.table = table

def _finished(self, reply):
    headers = reply.rawHeaderPairs()
    headers = {str(k):str(v) for k,v in headers}
    content_type = headers.get("Content-Type")

    # some code like "print headers.get("User-Agent")"

    url = reply.url().toString()
    status = reply.attribute(QNetworkRequest.HttpStatusCodeAttribute)
    status, ok = status.toInt()
    self.table.update([url, str(status), content_type])
```

Presently, the above code is showing only the URL,status and content type , but with this i also wants to display user agent.do someone has any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3906964/qt-qwebview-class-custom-user-agent
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13544413/need-help-override-a-function-qwebpage-useragentforurl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `User-Agent` is something which gets send to the server. This information is not sent from the server.

To set a user agent you can do the following with your `Manager` class for example:

```
from PyQt4.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest

manager = Manager()
request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://www.google.com/"))
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1")
manager.get(request)
```

And modify your `def _finished(self, reply):` method to get the request with the `User-Agent`:

```
def _finished(self, reply):
    print reply.request().rawHeader("User-Agent")
```

Comment: If you do not specify a `User-Agent` nothing is send and it will be an empty string (or PyQt4.QtCore.QByteArray) when you try to read it with `reply.request().rawHeader("User-Agent")`